# Is the pointer in c a normal variable or more than this

Tags: c++, c

i'm really confused when i write

```
int *ptr;
```

is this just a **normal variable** just hold the address of **another variable** or its a complex thing located in **CPU** registers for direct access

i need a clear answer **is the pointer a variable or not?**

Comment: Pointer is a normal variable. Behaves almost like an unsigned integer.

Comment: @jmajnert - thank you - could you help me with a link explain how pointer is so fast in execution

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: Do you have some relevant code or performance problems? Do you want to know how the compiler handles pointers? I think your question probably can't be reasonably answered like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pointer is a variable, in that it can be changed to point to other instances of the same data type.

In most processors, it is represented as an address within the processor's full address range.

The code generated by the compiler may emit code to load the value of the pointer variable into a register, then emit code to operate on the register.  One operation would be to dereference the pointer.  In other words, the compiler emits code to load a register with the value at the address represented by the pointer.  This is also known as indirection.

Although direct access is faster than indirect access, the difference in execution time is usually negligible.  For example, if a direct access takes 50 nanoseconds and indirection takes 60 nanoseconds, the difference would be 10 nanoseconds.  Your program would need to perform 100000 or more indirections to make a noticeable time difference.  There are special cases where this kind of optimizations is necessary; but not for most applications.  The time wasted waiting for User input or I/O from a hard drive makes the time difference between direct memory access and indirect memory access insignificant.

The fastest "variable" accesses are listed in order:

- Processor Register
- Direct fetching from the data cache.
- Direct fetching from memory on the chip, but outside the CPU core.
- Indirect fetching from memory on the chip, but outside the CPU core.
- Direct fetching from memory off of the System On a Chip.
- Indirect fetching from memory off of the System On a Chip.
- Fetching data from an I/O port.

If you think that indirection is still of concern, profile your code.  For high accuracy:

1. Find a test point (TP) on the hardware, LED, or some place you can
   connect an oscilloscope probe to.
2. Assert the test point.
3. Perform the operations at least 100,000 iterations.
4. Deassert the test point.
5. Measure the width of pulse shown by the oscilloscope.

Another method is to read the system clock, perform 1E09 iterations, read clock again.  Subtract the two clock readings.